# pyFLTK function `Fl.wait()` blocks all threads

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, fltk

When writing a multithreaded application using pyFLTK, I found a weird problem: When I call `Fl.wait()`  then all threads are stopped until another FLTK event appears. As a workaround `while Fl.check(): time.sleep(0.01)` works, but I'd prefer ot use simply `Fl.run()`.

I'm using pyfltk-1.3.0 and python-2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Fl::lock(); /* your code here */; Fl::unlock();`

Concurrent programming in FLTK 1.3 based applications is explained in this short article: http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/advanced.html#advanced_multithreading .

Comment: If I understand that article correctly, then Fl::lock() and Fl::unlock() only has to be used when accessing FLTK functions from multiple threads. What I was doing is run only a single thread that does anything with FLTK and another thread that does a completely independent thing (while True: print('X')). And the second thread stopped executing when I used Fl.run().

Comment: That is indeed a weird behaviour. I have never had such problem with FLTK, so can't really help... :(